Unable to invoke local custom GitHub Action
I am trying to invoke a custom github action which is in the same repository as the invoking workflow. I am invoking it like this
    - name: test action
      uses: MyOrg/MyRepo/.github/actions/my_action@master
      with:
        image: localhost/test-image:latest
        my_secret: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}

However I get Unable to Resolve Action
The file is there:
ls .github/actions/my_action.yaml 

What is the correct syntax for this use case?

Please checkout your repo first and then use relative path to access action in the repository, use . (dot)
- uses: actions/checkout@v2 # checkout 
- name: test action
  uses: ./.github/actions/my_action # Use relative path,No need to specify branch name
  with:
    image: localhost/test-image:latest
    my_secret: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}


Note: "uses: ./.github/actions/my_action" works if you put your custom action in ".github/actions/my_action/action.yaml", instead of ".github/actions/my_action.yaml".
